# How to search, score and order by score in array of object in MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose there are following type of MongoDB documents;

'tags'

```
[
{
_id:1,
name:[ 'C#', 'C#.NET', 'csharp' ]
},
_id:2,
name:[ '.NET', '.NET Framework', 'dotnet framework' ]
},
_id:3,
name:[ 'javascript', 'js' ]
}
]
```

'posts'

```
[
{
  _id: 1,
  contributer: { first: 'XXX', last: '-' },
  tags: [ { name: 'C#', tag_id: '1' }, { name: '.NET Framework', tag_id: '2' }  ]
},
{
  _id: 2,
  contributer: { first: 'YYY', last: '-' },
  tags: [ { name: 'javascript', tag_id: '3' } ]
},
{
  _id: 3,
  contributer: { first: 'XXX', last: '-' },
  tags: [ { name: '.NET Framework', tag_id: '2' } ]
}]
```

I would like to search by multiple tags such as;

```
{ 
  _ids: [1 ,2 ] 
}
```

in post documents which has over more than 1 million documents (and it is still growing) and order results by relevant to irrelivant.

I am looking for the advance solution to get fastests results by replacing better the document structure with existing one and other solutions (like map-reduce) and the optimum search query.

Expected results will be;

'results'

```
[
{
  _id: 1,
  contributer: { first: 'XXX', last: '-' },
  tags: [  { name: 'C#', tag_id: '1' }, { name: '.NET Framework', tag_id: '2' } ]
},
{
  _id: 3,
  contributer: { first: 'XXX', last: '-' },
  tags: [ { name: '.NET Framework', tag_id: '2' } ]
}]
```

I've tried following code-piece (multiple $elemmatch) so far;

```
db.posts.find(
   {
      tags: {
                $elemMatch: {
                     tag_id: "1", "2",
                },
                $elemMatch: {
                     tag_id: "1",
                },
      }
   }
)
```

But not sure if it is the only and best solution. You can include MongoDB or C# Driver codes. Thanks for advice!

Comment: Hello Mighty, I've edited the question and added the code piece. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is indexes, and I do recommend you spend some time defining indexes based on what you're searching. I would recommend using the explain() method to have a look at the query execution plan and see what you can improve. If your query goes 100% on collection scan, it's going to be horrendously slow.

Not sure if you've done it, but can't recommend highly enough the FREE course for .NET devs on MongoDB university (https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M101N/about).

Comment: Hello Andrei, Thank you for your answer. There is a defined single index on tag_id. I have had the M101N lessons while MongoDB has the 2.4 version and I had the certificate of it.

Comment: It might be useful to add a new index on the tags array, so that the query can use the index scan